# VSE, python API: get time point in video file under marker

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

There is a scene in Video Sequence Editor with several video strips one after another in time. Each strip corresponds to a video file. Along the timeline I have several markers.

What I'd like to do is to take a marker and return a videofile path under the marker and a time position in this video file at which marker points.
I'm thinking of writing  a python script to do that automatically for a long scene with lots of markers. What would be a preferred way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will print the Marker time (in seconds since it's corresponding video strip started) with it's corresponding video strip's path for every marker in the scene's timeline.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

fps = scene.render.fps / scene.render.fps_base

all_markers = sorted(scene.timeline_markers, key=lambda m: m.frame)

all_strips = list(sorted(scene.sequence_editor.sequences,
            key=lambda x: x.frame_final_start))

for strip in all_strips:
    if strip.type == 'MOVIE':
        start = strip.frame_final_start
        end = strip.frame_final_end

        for marker in all_markers:    
            if marker.frame >= start and marker.frame <= end:
                time = (marker.frame - start) / fps
                path = strip.filepath
                print(time, path)
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. One thing I guess is that time should be 
"time = (marker.frame - start) / fps"
since I want to get the time in strips' file

Comment: Right. I'll adjust the answer to make it more accurate.

Comment: you can *filter* your list to get only the movie strips: `strips_movie = (i for i in strips_all_sorted if i.type == 'MOVIE')` 

this returns a generator so it should be very memory friendly - if you exchange the `()` to `[]` you will get a normal list